# Trying to display images from a filesystem in php

Tags: php

Today i am looking for help. This is my first time asking so sorry in advance if I make a few mistakes
I am trying to code a small web application that will display images.Originally I used the blob format to store my images in a database, however from researching on here People suggest to use a file system. My issue is I cannot display an image. It could be a very small error or even a bad reference to a files location however I cannot make it work.
This is a small project that I hope to be able to improve on and hopefully create into a sort of photo gallery. I am running this application on a localhost.

I am having an issue with displaying images from a filesystem.

```
// index.php
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

My form then leads to a process page where the request is dealt with.

```
  <?php
 // process.php

 // connect to the database
 include 'connection.php';
 // take in some file data
 $filename =$_FILES['image']['name'];
 // get the file extension
 $extension = strtolower(substr($filename, strpos($filename, '.')+1));

// if the file name is set
if(isset($filename)){

// set save destination
$saved ='images/'; 

// rename file 
$filename = time().rand().".".$extension;

$tmp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
// move image to the desired folder
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $saved.$filename)){ 
echo "Success!";

// if success insert location into database
$insert="INSERT INTO stored (folder_name,file_name) VALUES('$saved',   '$filename')";
// if the query is correct
if($result=mysqli_query($con,$insert)){
echo "DONE";
echo"</br>";
// attempt to print image
echo "<img src=getimage.php?file_name=$filename>";
}

}
}

else{
 echo "Please select a photo!!";
}
?>
```

Now as you can see I have an < img > tag. To try and learn, I was trying to just display the recently uploaded image. To try and do this I created a getimage file.

```
<?php
 //getimage.php

// set the page to display images
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

include "connection.php";

// get requested filename
$name = ($_GET['file_name']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM stored WHERE file_name=$name";

$image = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($image,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$img = $row['file_name'];

echo $img;
?>
```

My database structure is as follows:
     database name = db_file.
     table name = stored.
     columns = folder_name, file_name

Again, this is just a small project so I know I will have to alter the database if I wish to create a larger more efficient application.

Comment: What does not work as expected? Please give a more detailed description of your problem. ;) Maybe you can test seaparate parts of you code.

Comment: The database connection calls within the 'getimage.php' script seem redundant in the code above  - you already define the image name in the code above.

Comment: If you show all errors with the following (top of the file); `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and 
`ini_set('display_errors', '1');` Do you get any errors?

Comment: @matthias Thanks for the reply. I was used to displaying a blop image from a database but I have never dealt with a file system. originally I would get the image source like :

    echo "<img src=getupload.php?id=$lastid>";

However when using the file system it seems to be not working.

Comment: @Bono I dont get any errors. I get the broken image symbol .
This leads me to believe that my reference to the image is wrong.
I just cant see where

Comment: @RamRaider the getimage file is there to get and display the image.
I have that files header set to jpeg so I can display images. 
Again this is how i did it for blob image types stored in a database not a file system

Comment: I would inspect the filename output `$row['file_name'];` and manually check for the file in a first step.

Comment: @matthias how do you mean check for the file?
isset($row['file_name'])?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you use the database lookup to get just the file name, but you already have the file name. Try adding the folder name, create a valid path.

change

```
$img = $row['file_name'];
```

to

```
$img = $row['folder_name'] . '/' . $row['file_name'];
```

check your `<img>`tag to see if the correct url is present. You may or may not need the '/', it depends on how you stored the folder name. You may need to add the domain name. There is just not enough information know what is needed.

Your `<img>` should look like this

```
<img href="http://www.yourdomain.com/folder name/file name">
```

in the end

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
My getimage file now looks like this.

    $image = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    // gain access to the associative array 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($image,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $img = $row['folder_name'] . '/' . $row['file_name'];
    echo $img;

However im still getting the broken image icon in chrome.

Comment: @DetectiveClarke: the echo command simply prints out the folder and file name. So have a look at your filesystem if this file really exists and is referenced correctly. I suggest you to add file names to your scripts above. Also mention what exactly you are viewing with your browser.

Comment: @matthias I can see in my phpmyadmin that the uplaod was successful.
example : images/
14253848974144.jpg

Would i check in the getimage file if the image exists?

I have also added file names thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @DetectiveClarke phpMyAdmin only lets you check that for the uploaded file a dataset was saved. But okay, this should only be done if `move_uploaded_file` returns successfully. But can you see the uploade file in the system? Like check with (S)FTP client. Try to access the image within the full URL name, e.g. http://localhost/myproject/images/14253848974144.jpg

Comment: @matthias yes the uploaded image shows up when i enter the images saved file name in the above format.

Comment: @DetectiveClarke ok, then your attempt to embedd the image should simplify to `echo "<img src=\"", $saved.$filename, "\>";`. You just need an `img`-Tag in HTML that provides the URL to the picture. The browser will load it itself. There is no need to select data from the database, except you'd like to check if this image exists in the database.

Comment: @matthias  unfortunately because im new i cannot bring this discussion to chat.

in my process.php my attempt to print the image now reads

     echo "<img src=\"", $saved.$filename, "\>";

However the broken image icon has vanished. So this leads me to believe that i need the getimage.php file to display the image as its header is set to jpeg.

Comment: @DetectiveClarke: it depends what you want to do. Output the file? Then output the header and use `readfile`. If you want to embedd it into an HTML website simply use the `<img>`-Tag of HTML. If you output an image-Header and HTML-Code this won't work out. As the image is kind of binary output and the HTML-Code output is also interpreted as part of this image.

Comment: @matthias i want to display the image on the screen. My idea is to create a web app that displays a bunch of photos in a sort of gallery.

The image-header is on a get page which returns the photo from the details provided in the database. I then use the < img > .

        // attempt to print image
 echo "<img src=\"", $saved.$filename, "\>";